# How to save and load history between invocations of Scala JLine

Tags: scala, jline

I'm using [Scala JLine](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.scala-lang.virtualized%7Cjline%7C2.10.2-RC1%7Cjar) in my CLI program.  It's working fine, but it forgets my history every time I restart my program.  I see a class called `FileHistory`, and I see the `ConsoleReader` class has a method called `setHistory()` which takes an instance of `FileHistory`.  I would expect calling that method would cause it to create or load and save a file containing my history.  But it doesn't.

Unfortunately the documentation is nigh nonexistent.  How can I make it so the next time I run my JLine-enabled program it remembers the commands that I had typed in the previous run?

### Update

Correct answer given below by mirandes.  Thanks to mirandes and som-snytt both for their helpful (yea solvent) responses.

Comment: JLine is actually a separate library, Scala only has it embedded in its distribution.

Comment: My flush answer arrived first... BTW.

Comment: Your response did arrive first by seven hours, som-snytt.  I agree.  Kudos to you for speed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import scala.tools.jline.console.ConsoleReader
import scala.tools.jline.console.history.FileHistory
import java.io.File

val reader : ConsoleReader = new ConsoleReader() 

val history = new FileHistory(new File(".history"))
reader.setHistory(history)
```

Before exiting the app, make sure you flush the history.

```
reader.getHistory.asInstanceOf[FileHistory].flush()
```

Comment: And it's saving a file called `.history` in the same directory from which you run the program?  Are you doing anything to save the file before your program exits?  Maybe I'm quitting my program wrong.

Comment: I have edited the answer to add a necessary `flush()` in the end. It can save in the current dir, or at any full path you want.

Comment: Works, thanks!!  One thing though: I had to change `new File(".history")` to `(new File(".history")).getAbsoluteFile` for some reason.  I'm guessing it has something to do with `sbt`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a comment.  I thought you said there wasn't any documentation?

```
/**
 * {@link History} using a file for persistent backing.
 * <p/>
 * Implementers should install shutdown hook to call {@link FileHistory#flush}
 * to save history to disk.
 *
 * @author <a href="mailto:jason@planet57.com">Jason Dillon</a>
 * @since 2.0
 */
public class FileHistory
```

Compare to [Scala REPL internal history](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/repl/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/session/FileBackedHistory.scala#L15).

Comment: Obviously I need to work on my documentation-finding skills.  I don't see this in the javadocs jar that comes with the Scala-version maven artifact, nor did I see it when I looked at [the Java version docs here](http://jline.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html).  Now I see I was looking at the wrong version.  And there's no javadocs on the v2 site [here](http://jline.github.io/jline2/project-info.html).  Oh yeah, [it's right here](https://github.com/jline/jline2/blob/master/src/main/java/jline/console/history/FileHistory.java).  How did I miss that?  Thank you!