# Is it possible to rerun a command in spark-shell via its history number?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'd like to be able to run a spark-shell command via it's history number. When I type :history or :h?, I then cut and paste the command - even though the history command gives it an ID number. I'd like to be able to type

```
:61
```

or something to just rerun the command. Is there something like that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can press `control + R`, then start typing to search for your command. You can then press enter to run, or you can edit the command before running, like in readline.

Answer (score 7):

Yes It is possible to use the use HISTORY command in spark shell

**scala> :history**

or

**scala> :22**

or

**scala> ctrl + r**

Answer (score 3):

dpeacock's answer is probably the best you can get currently.

[If you look at this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935184/how-to-save-and-load-history-between-invocations-of-scala-jline) you can see that you could load the history yourself, but loading and running it is another story as I cannot seem to find a way to get access to the `ILoop` variable, which is the interactive loop that you could run an `interpret` command through.

To load the history, just do

```
val history = new FileHistory(new File("HOME/.spark_history"))
history.index //gives you the current number
history.moveTo(NUMBER) //moves the cursor
history.current //gives you the command you want
```

You could wrap this all up in an object, but without the `ILoop` you would still need to copy and paste. So....**the short answer is not really**

Answer (score 2):

In Linux it will be present in
`/home/<userid>/scala_history` for spark-shell

Comment: scala_history is hidden file so it should be `$HOME/.scala_history`